# How to find product by manufacturer?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am using Laravel 8 and using Raw Query. I have added query to fetch count of product by manufacturers but facing below error.

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'ngtonlin_superadmin.m.manufacturerid'
isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `m`.`manufacturerid` as `id`, `m`.`name`, `m`.`logowidth`,
`m`.`logoheight`, count(p.id) as total from `products` as `p` inner join `manufacturer` as `m` on
`m`.`manufacturerid` = `p`.`manufacturer_id` group by `p`.`manufacturer_id` order by `total` desc limit 5)
```

and my query is

```
DB::table('products as p')
        ->select('m.manufacturerid as id','m.name','m.logowidth','m.logoheight', DB::raw('count(p.id) as total'))
        ->join('manufacturer as m','m.manufacturerid','=','p.manufacturer_id')
        ->groupBy('p.manufacturer_id')
        ->orderBy('total', 'DESC')
        ->limit(5)
        ->get();
```

Comment: You need to include all non-aggregated columns that are you your select in your `groupBy` as well. In your case that's `m.name, m.logowidth, m.logoheight`

Comment: Can you please tell me which column I add?

Comment: You need to add ALL COLUMNS that are in the SELECT that are not being aggregated (surrounded by AVG(), MIN(), MAX(), etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use

```
->groupBy('m.manufacturerid', 'm.name','m.logowidth','m.logoheight')
```

Not

```
->groupBy('p.manufacturer_id')
```

Because, I think p.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturerid, and you use m.manufacturerid in the select part.

Comment: If it works, can you give me the answer?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
DB::table('products as p')->join('manufacturer as m','m.manufacturerid','p.manufacturer_id')->selectRaw('m.manufacturerid as id')->selectRaw('m.name')->selectRaw('m.logowidth')->selectRaw('m.logoheight')->selectRaw('count(p.id) as total')->groupBy('p.manufacturer_id')->orderBy('total', 'DESC')->limit(5)->get();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).